# andThen Function and forEach Function applied on a stream

Tags: java

Given the piece of code below, I am failing to understand how it returns this output:

```
* 2 = 2
1 * 2 = 4
2 * 2 = 6
3

public static void generateMultiplicationTable(int number){
Stream<Integer> sin = Stream.of(1, 2, 3 );
Consumer<Integer> c1 = System.out::print;
Consumer<Integer> c2 = x->{ System.out.println(" * "+number+" = "+x*number); };

sin.forEach(c2.andThen(c1));}
```

I understand how the andThen works, taking the output from the first function and applying it to the second function as input, based on this understanding, it should return this:

```
* 2 = 2
* 2 = 4
* 2 = 6
```

Comment: *"taking the output from the first function and applying it to the second function as input"* ... how should that be possible when `c2` prints something directly into the console and doesn't return anything? Do you now have an idea what `c1` passes as an argument to `print`?

Comment: Have a look at the Javadoc for and the implementation of `andThen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`andThen` is implemented similar to this:

```
default Consumer<T> andThen(Consumer<? super T> after) {
    return (T t) -> { 
        this.accept(t); 
        after.accept(t); 
    };
}
```

So the `forEach` call can be rewritten as:

```
sin.forEach(number -> {
    c2.accept(number);
    c1.accept(number);
});
```

So for the first element of the stream, `c2` prints `* 2 = 2` and a new line, `c1` prints `1`. The second element causes `c2` to print `* 2 = 4` and a new line, and `c1` to print `2`, and so on.

If you actually want a multiplication table, you should run `c1` first, i.e. `c1.andThen(c2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, but from my understanding is that the first element stream 1 is sent to the first function c2, which gives the output *2=2 this output is then sent to the c1 function which prints out? 
Why does c1 get the stream elements itself? shouldn't it only get the output from c2 function?

Comment: @M.B I think you are confusing `Consumer` and `Function`. They both have an `andThen` method, but does different things. You seem to be also confusing “output (to the console)” and “return value”. What you described in your comment is what `Function.andThen` does. The _return value_ of the first function (not what it prints on the screen!) gets passed to the second function. OTOH, consumers don’t have return values, so the only way you can compose them is to run them one after another.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the distinction, I read about the two versions of andThen and do understand them in the simple examples provided at geeksforgeeks. Still don't understand why it is printing this? What is the 'return value' from the c2 function for stream 1 or 2? Thank you so much for any clarification!

Comment: @M.B Consumers don't return anything. `c2.andThen(c1)` creates a new consumer that, when given a parameter `x`, runs `c2` with `x`, then runs `c1` with `x`. On the other hand, if `f1` and `f2` are `Function<T, U>` and `Function<U, V>` respectively, then `f1.andThen(f2)` creates a new `Function<T, V>` that, when given a parameter `x`, evaluates `f2(f1(x))`. Now read my answer again.

Comment: ohh okay, yup I got it! So, in Consumer the f1 function is not a parameter to the second f2 function. They work in parallel! Wonderful thank you sooooooo much! For this awesome explanation. I truly appreciate it :)